# Change a VARCHAR field via migration in Vapor Fluent-MySQL

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent, fluent-mysql

I'm using `Vapor 3` and `FluentMySQL` for my new project and want to change maximum length of a field (`varchar(N)`) via migration. How can I do this?

I have a Model named `Word` in my project and one of its fields is `sourceIdentifier` that is `String` and have maximum length of 12. The model is something like this:

```swift
final class Word: MySQLModel {
    ...other properties

    var sourceIdentifier: String

    ...other properties
}
```

At the beginning, I thought 5 is enough for the field and used this code to create `Table` for this model:

```swift
static func prepare(on conn: MySQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
    return MySQLDatabase.create(Word.self, on: conn) { builder in
        ...other fields...

        builder.field(for: \.sourceIdentifier, type: .varchar(5, characterSet: nil, collate: nil))

        ...other fields...
    }
}
```

As you see above, the table created with field `sourceIdentifier` and its type is `.varchar(5, characterSet: nil, collate: nil)`.

Now I want to increase maximum length of the field via migration.

I also tried `MySQLDatabase.update` like this:

```swift
static func prepare(on conn: MySQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
    return MySQLDatabase.update(Word.self, on: conn) { builder in
        builder.field(for: \.sourceIdentifier, type: .varchar(12, characterSet: nil, collate: nil))
    }
}
```

and it didn't work; Nothing happened.

How can I change structure of the table via `Vapor`, `FluentMySQL` and migrations?

Answer (score 2):

You could do anything with raw query like this

```swift
static func prepare(on conn: MySQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
    return conn.raw("ALTER TABLE emp MODIFY COLUMN name VARCHAR(100);").run()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
static func prepare(on conn: MySQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
  return Database.create(self, on: connection) { builder in
    builder.field(for: \.id, type: .bigint(20), .primaryKey)
    builder.field(for: \.fieldA, type: .varchar(12))
    builder.field(for: \.fieldB, type: .bigint(20))
  }
}
```

Instead of using `addProperties(to:)` to add all the fields to the database, you could use `field(for:type:_:)` to add fields manually.